# define variable using using "dirname "$(readlink -f "$0")

Tags: bash, shell

how to define a dir path as variable using "dirname "$(readlink -f "$0")

I want to define /user/local/dirname to that variable and use in my script

Comment: See [BashFAQ/028 (How do I determine the location of my script? ...)](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/028), particularly the [Why $0 is NOT an option](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/028#Why_.240_is_NOT_an_option) section.  Avoid [How can I get the source directory of a Bash script from within the script itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59895/4154375).  Most of the answers contain code that doesn't work in general.